# What do double curly braces do in a bash command?

Tags: python, bash, command, escaping, curly-braces

I am refactoring a script and I'm seeing this:

```
/bin/bash -c 'rm -rf directory/{{..?*,.[!.]*,*}}'
```

Googling "bash double curly braces" is strangely not getting my anywhere so far. What does this code do?

EDIT: I didn't include enough details, apparently. It's actually a python command that was using `format()`, so the double curly braces were actually single curly braces being escaped for that.

```
subprocess.check_output(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'rm -rf {0}/{{..?*,.[!.]*,*}}'.format('directory')]
```

@thatotherguy nailed it in the comments.

Comment: What kind of script are you refactoring?  Are you sure the `{{` isn't used for some kind of templating or escaping in the outer script?

Comment: @thatotherguy Well, it's a python script that uses `subprocess.check_output()` to run the command, but there is no templating going on. What I display is what is executed.

Comment: It looks like a typo for `bash -c 'rm -rf directory/{..?*,.[!.]*,*}'` unless `directory` actually does contain files/directories whose names begin with `{` and end with `}` - try `echo directory/{{..?*,.[!.]*,*}}` and `echo directory/{..?*,.[!.]*,*}`

Comment: @mattalxndr Would you mind posting it with more context and without redactions anways? I'm guessing the real code is something like `subprocess.check_output("/bin/bash -c '{}/{{..?*,.[!.]*,*}}'".format("mydirectory"))` which would explain it

Comment: @thatotherguy You were right. If you add that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @mattalxndr Since it turned out to be a Python issue and unrelated to double curly braces and Bash, I would suggest deleting the question under the "was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers" clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the double curly appears when passing a bash script in a GitLab or GitHub runner for example

```
  - name: Set selected color
    run: echo '::set-output name=SELECTED_COLOR::green'
    id: random-color-generator
  - name: Get color
    run: echo "The selected color is ${{ steps.random-color-generator.outputs.SELECTED_COLOR }}"
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions

Comment: Yes, it was a template. Thanks for the answer.